# Can i retrieve Google Analytics events count on Android and IOS applications to display in my app?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics to track Mobile application events, there is any chance to retrieve back this data to display in my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the google analytics reporting api to retrieve ga data and display in your app. Note the data won't be in realtime and will be updated based on what's outlined in your plan.